# context canceled during getting session

Tags: database, go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-spanner

I have a go app that wants to talk to a spanner database (not emulator).
Following is the erroneous code snippet.

```
c, err := createClient(ctx, cfg.Database.SpannerConnStr)

if err != nil {
    log2.Fatalf("failed to connect to Spanner: %e", err)
}

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, dbTimeout)
defer cancel()
row, err := c.Single().ReadRow(ctx, "Books", spanner.Key{"6c68363e-ac82-4dfe-9a0a-d49b77d4441a"}, []string{"author"})
```

The database string reads `projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/databases/my-db` as expected

I have explicitly set environment variable `SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST=""`

But when I run the app, the database read operation times out with the error: `"spanner: code = \"DeadlineExceeded\", desc = \"timeout / context canceled during getting session.\""`

I can query the same database through my terminal using the `gcloud spanner databases execute-sql` command and the `dbTimeout` has been set to 30 seconds (which I think is more than enough time).

Running on `MacOS 13.4` and `go1.19.1 darwin/arm64`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the client still tries to connect to the emulator. Try to execute `unset SPANNER_EMULATOR_HOST` instead of setting it to an empty string.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. Still the same issue.

Comment: Found the issue. It was something to do with the internal network and adding the appropriate hosts to /etc/hosts file worked.